# how to read mp3 files from internal and external storage on Android?

Tags: java, android

My code is below. It finds all of the mp3 in my external sd card storage. I need to read all mp3 files from internal storage. MediaStore is to complexed for me. I managed to do it a year ago, but have lost the file. If someone could help me out that would great. I have not been able to easily find the information I need therefor I am searching here. This will be of a lot of use to me so answer or suggestions will be well appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;


public class SongsManager {



    final String MEDIA_PATH = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";



    // Constructor
    public SongsManager() {

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: `MEDIA_PATH = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";`. Did you really say that `File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);` would be suited to get files from an sd card?

Comment: Sorry my friend was rushed. If you please, could you explain how I could go about modifying this this to read my internal storage?

Comment: I do not know what you consider to be internal storage. But if you have the 'path' to it `scanDirectory(new File(path));` should work.

Comment: I mean music that or storage that is on the solid state drive. I'm referring to android development.

Comment: You are referring to what? And you do not react on 'path'? Are you here for help?